# Can't inject WebServiceContext

Tags: java, weblogic, jax-ws

I'm  having a hard time trying to make WebServiceContext to be injected. My Code is as follows:

```
@WebService(name = "ISTService", targetNamespace = "com.zinc.my.ist", endpointInterface = "com.zinc.my.ist.RicService", wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/istSoap.wsdl")
@SchemaValidation(handler = SchemaValidationErrorHandler.class)
public class ISTServiceImpl implements ISTService {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext wsContext;
```

I've developed many other webservices in other projects, and this has always worked, with same Mvn dependencies.

In this specific when I publish the war in weblogic, I'm getting:

> Module named 'ist-webServices' failed to deploy. See Error Log view
> for more detail. weblogic.application.ModuleException:
> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup
> 'com.zinc.my.ist.impl.ISTServiceImpl/wsContext' didn't find subcontext
> 'com'. Resolved ''; remaining name
> 'com.zinc.my.ist.impl.ISTServiceImpl/wsContext'

I've searched for identic issues. I found someone who had to add @Resource(name="wsContext"). In my case it doesn't work. I don't know if this is some kind of CDI mixup.

Someone knows or can give me a hint about what is happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it is related to the case of the resource you are trying to use.

Very often, people restart their webapplication and wait some time to get the link done between their webapps and the resources exposed by external webservices or JNDI resources or microservices too.

And more important, they use JNDI path compatible with weblogic environment. Something like `"java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDB"` for a datasource. I bet it is the same for webservices. Go to the admin console and check if the JNDI name of your webservice is referenced well, and use its own name.

To access the Weblogic admin console you can see the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/fr/solutions/wls-on-prem-to-oci/access-weblogic-admin-console.html#GUID-AC70C290-10E0-4A32-9171-F77587EB464C) : `http://localhost:7001/console` but there are some steps to make it available.

You can look inside webservices console if any WSDL is deployed
@see https://www.syntax.com/how-to-find-the-elusive-wsdl-urls-in-weblogic/?lang=fr

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Would you know where I can see that info in Weblogic console.. I've there service name, and nothing more.

Comment: I've juste edited my answer to give you Weblogic admin console information.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I managed to understand than injection is nor performed because I've deltaspike dependencies in my project. Somehow the behaviour is altered by deltaspike.

Comment: Okay so it works now ;)